# Adding extension bundle identifier to main app .plist

Tags: ios, swift, walletextension

Currently working on wallet extension and need to add both UI and NonUI extension bundle identifier to the main app .plist. As per my understanding we can add only one identifier but incase if multiple identifiers needs to be added then how it can be done.

Note: For both extension different target and .plist is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add neither UI nor NonUI extension's bundle ID's to main target's Info.plist file.

Wallet extensions are working properly without it, just if you correctly setup your extensions's plists (as you did, you say), entitlement files and archive your project with providing all required provisioning profiles for those extensions.